# Javascript selection offset

Tags: javascript, jquery, selection

I'm trying to get the offset of a collapsed Javascript selection.

Here is an example of a DOM element where I put my collapsed selection before the word "world":

```
<p>some text <strong>some bolded text</strong> hello |world</p>
```

I want to get the offset of "world" relative to `<p>`, which is 53.

The problem is that selection.focusNode returns the text between `</strong>` and `</p>`, which is " hello world".

And calling selection.getRangeAt(0).startOffset returns the offset of my selection inside the focusNode, which is 7.

How can I get the offset from `<p>`?

Comment: How about retrieving [`endOffset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/endOffset)?

Comment: Selection is collapsed so endOffset=startOffset